# Why is the menu item not showing as an action?

Tags: android, xml

this is the xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/main_main_prefs"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_tune_white_24px"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings"
        android:visible="true"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

[image: This is the Android studio render]
  But this is the case in actual device:
[image: Actual Device]

**Update:** this is the menu inflation code. And the picture is the response in real device.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        (new MenuInflater(this)).inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.main_main_prefs:
                Toasty.info(this,"Prefs Was Clicked").show();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

[image: the response]

Comment: Are you sure you have inflated correct menu file? Check the menu id in `inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);`

Comment: yes i am pretty sure.

Comment: Can you post the code.

Comment: @TragedyHero try android:showAsAction="always"

Comment: @nomag see the code , it is already there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create menu like this

```
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
```

instead of

```
(new MenuInflater(this)).inflate(R.menu.main,menu);
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `android:orderInCategory`. Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/main_main_prefs"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_tune_white_24px"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:visible="true"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```